# How to prevent formulas to change when I cut and paste the referenced cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have J column validating if the contents on the B and E columns are the same so I can make some adjustments in the sheet, as in the picture below

[image]

J column formula is =IF(E663=B663;"si";"CAMBIAR"), and it allows me to identify where I have to move the content one cell below, because I needed to update the values in the sheet. When the value is CAMBIAR (CHANGE IN ENGLISH) I select all the cells in the columns D and E and cut them and paste them one row below.

At that moment the formulas in J column change to =IF(E665=B664;"si";"CAMBIAR"). Note the rows are not the same anymore, B is stuck in the last row. I expect both to be 665. I have to refresh the formulas each time making this work tedious. How can I prevent excel to make that change? I tried using absolute formulas with the $ sign on both cell references but excel doesn't car and changes it anyway.

Comment: I answered this back on Stack Overflow.  Your question is appropriate there.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69577935/how-to-pevent-formulas-to-change-when-i-cut-and-paste-the-referenced-cells/69578043#69578043

Comment: Should I delete this one?

Comment: usually it is frowned upon to ask the same question in two different stack sites.  But it is up to you.